# Find the f(any value) e.g f(1) or f(2), of a function that the user enter

Tags: matlab

The main problem here is to evaluate the user function at some point because we don't know if the user will enter a function in x domain or another domain

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
function y = f(~)
y = input('Enter you function: ');
end
```

and this is what I want:

```
>>f
Enter you function: a^2+3*a-3
>>f(1)
ans =
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution almost provides the exact requirements in your question. I'd feel kind of queezy using this though with the EVAL. You'd also want to wrap some error checking into this.

```
classdef f < handle

    properties (Access = private)
        functionString = '';
    end

    methods
        function obj = f
            if nargin == 0
                obj.functionString = input('Enter your function: ', 's');
            end
        end

        function value = subsref(obj, a)
            a = a.subs{:};
            value = eval(obj.functionString);
        end

        function display(obj)

        end
    end

end
```

You can then use this class like:

```
>> a = f
Enter your function: a^2+3*a-3
>> a(1)

ans =

     1

>> a(2)

ans =

     7
```

Comment: cool, it works fine! OK, if I want it returns the initial value (i.e f(0)) of a laplace function (e.g if we have F(s), fs = (s^2+6*s+9)/(s^3+2*s^2-s-2) and then we find f(t) which is equal to ft = ilaplace(fs); how to find f(t) at value 0) that's all I want to do

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Change the line in the above class from `a = a.subs{:};` to `t = a.subs{:};`. At the command line run `ilaplace(fs)`, copy the result, run the above class by entering `a = f` at the command line and paste when prompted for a function.

Comment: @b3: is there a way to include ilaplace method into the class so I don't have to copy and paste anything

Comment: -1. Instead of addressing the obvious and severe lack of understanding of the asker, this answer provides, with no caveats, an extremely poor solution. This is bad programming practice, and fails to help the asker actually understand anything.

Comment: @Colin K: It's good to see that you care enough to have an opinion but you are making some wild assumptions. This is a Q&A site. I gave an A after which there was plenty of opportunity for the OP to clarify if necessary. I wonder if you checked whether or not the OP gained some understanding before you formed your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use function handles:

```
>> f=@(x) x^2+3*x-3

f = 

    @(x)x^2+3*x-3

>> f(1)

ans =

     1

>> f(2)

ans =

     7
```